# Embedded Jetty: Setting JVM arguments

Tags: java, scala, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded instance of Jetty running in my app, which apparently creates another instance of JVM. How can I pass JVM arguments to this instance? I create my embedded Jetty like this:

```
val server = new Server
val scc = new SelectChannelConnector
scc.setPort(8080)
server.setConnectors(Array(scc))

val context = new WebAppContext()
context.setServer(server)
context.setContextPath("/")
context.setWar("src/main/webapp")

server.addHandler(context)

try {
    println(">>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP")
    server.start()
    while (System.in.available() == 0) {
        Thread.sleep(5000)
    }
    server.stop()
    server.join()
} catch {
    case exc:
    Exception => {
        exc.printStackTrace()
        System.exit(100)
    }
}
```

(Scala code but I believe it's easy to understand for Java devs as well)

Comment: What makes you think another JVM instance is created?

Answer (score 1):

Starting a server in Jetty like this will not result in a new process being created. If you want to set jvm parameters that affect the embedded jetty server you need to ensure that the process creating the server is run with the appropriate settings. Alternatively, you could launch a process having setup everything appropriately but this will require some additional work to monitor the process, etc.